# How to rotate an image on the canvas and expand the parent so that the image is not cut away?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, image-rotation

How to rotate an image on an HTML5 Canvas, without loosing any image data? I mean if rotation causes the image dimensions to increase, I want to expand the Canvas container as well, so that the image is not cut off. The following image might say better:
[image]

The brown colored box is actually the container that wraps the Canvas. I want to expand it (and the Canvas to fit the image) when the Canvas is rotated, so that the image is not cut off.

**Update:**
The image could be larger than the Canvas hence I'm using a bounding box method to calculate proportional sizes with the parent container to fit the image. So the Canvas's `style` dimensions will be the calculated ones whereas it's height and width attributes will be the image dimensions.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function will resize your canvas to exactly fit the rotated image.  You must supply the width and height of the image and it's current rotation angle in degrees.

[Edited: OOPS! I should have converted the angle to radians ... And ... the **canvas** width/height should be changed, not the **css** width/height]

```
function resizeCanvasContainer(w,h,a){
var newWidth,newHeight;
  var rads=a*Math.PI/180;
  var c = Math.cos(rads);
  var s = Math.sin(rads);

    if (s < 0) { s = -s; }
    if (c < 0) { c = -c; }
    newWidth = h * s + w * c;
    newHeight = h * c + w * s ;

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = newWidth + 'px';
canvas.height = newHeight + 'px';
}
```

Comment: Hey man great... I'll try this...! Also, I need you to know this, I'm calculating the style dimensions for the canvas based on its parent container, like bounding box, as the image is many a times way too large than the container. Does that fact affect this solution?

Comment: It is still cutting my Canvas bro, hence losing image corners!

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle showing how the canvas can be resized to allow a fixed sized element to rotate 360 degrees without falling out of the canvas..... http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/CuRan/4/

Comment: Dude, I tweaked it a bit and it works! In my case we didn't have the image sizes beforehand since images are loaded on the fly and their sizes are applied to the Canvas. Thanks!

Comment: How good are you with Geometry? I really need some help with angular displacement in an issue.

Comment: Glad I could help.  By angular displacement, do you mean transferring an angle in a 2d plane?  That I can do...but when you start transferring angles in 3d space my mind starts getting fuzzy.

Comment: Yep, 2d... Actually I was trying the browser based rotation, but then my crop would go crazy as the pixels would displace after the rotation. So I need to calculate a pixels actual position after rotating the image.

Comment: Anyways since this solution works, could you please tell me how to identify the blank areas of the canvas after the image is rotated? Meaning I want to handle mouse clicks only on the rotated image and not the empty space around it...

Comment: We're getting a bit off-topic, but rather than calculating empty space for hit-testing, try one of these 3 common methods for hit-testing a rotated rectangle:

---- (1). Assuming that the rectangle is rotated clockwise, rotate the clicked point counter-clockwise around the same registration point as the rectangle and then do a hittest against the rectangle’s un-rotated position. ----continued on next comment----

Comment: (2). Keep a second hidden canvas with a same sized/same rotated rectangle, but this “mirror” rectangle is solid red.  Then just test the color under the mouseclick on the "mirror" to see if it’s red.  Sounds CRAZY doesn’t it, but it works very well and is commonly used!

  ---- (3). Use a canvas library that tracks shapes/images you draw on the canvas and does hit-testing. Good libs: easeljs, kineticjs,  fabricjs